# Verified App Still Gets "App isn't verified" Screen

Tags: google-app-engine

I've gone through the process of filling out the OAuth Developer Verification Form and verifying ownership of web domains. I even received an email from the Google Cloud Platform support saying that the app has access to the scopes that are desired (e.g. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file), but when I try to make a connection from the app to Google, it gives me the screen saying that the app isn't verified:
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs2N1.png)

What could I be missing that would cause this to continue happening? Am I missing some settings that need to be enabled or something?

Comment: Did you add any additional scope later after you got approved with some scope?

Comment: @BravinBalasubramaniam Not that I know of, I've only gone through this verification process once.

Comment: Interesting, just send an email regarding the issue in the same email thread.

Comment: I have the same issue. Is there a solution for this ?